# accept or discard changes using unified diff output from CLI

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff

Using git I often find myself with formatting changes that I did not intend to make.  Normally I'll use a merge/diff tool and step through the changes accepting/rejecting modifications.

Is there some way to use the unified diff information to quickly accept / reject the changes to the modified files from the CLI?

If the output of the diff tells me changes at: @@ -104,7 +124,7 @@
Is there a good way to accept or reject changes using that same contextual information?

```
magictool "@@ -104,7 +124,7 @@" accept|reject
```

Would not be hard to write something to do it, is there a common way to do this without writing my own tool?

Comment: Isn't this sort of what `git add -p` gets you?

Comment: Thanks larsks; I have never used -p before that is quite helpful.  However, that is interactive and requires a step through the changes.  I'd like to diff, copy the unified diff contextual information to clipboard, ctrl-c out diff, and use CLI to quickly pin point the change.

Comment: additionally, implementation need not require git but any old patch file.